# How to make display change onclick()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change display to block by clicking this icon:

```
<div class="index-navi-frame-box">
   <p onclick="expandFunction()">
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
   </p>
</div>
```

And this is what it should change

```
<div class="index-navi-expended"></div>
```

Css:

```
.index-navi-expended{
width: 100%;
height: 30%;
background-color: #757575;
position: relative;
display: none;
```

}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onclick in one element show another element in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368104/onclick-in-one-element-show-another-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery, you can remove the old and add the new class like this:

```
$(".index-navi-frame-box").on("click", function() {

    $(this).removeClass("index-navi-frame-box").addClass("index-navi-expended);

});
```

However, if possible I would recommend that the new class is just overwriting the styles of the old class, so you can just add the new class without removing the old class.

Try to avoid inline JavaScript (`onclick=""`) and place the code above either in a separate .js file or in `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".index-navi-frame-box p").click(function() {
  $(".index-navi-expanded").css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With pure JavaScript, you can just use the [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) property to toggle the classes like this:

```js
var x = document.querySelector(".index-navi-frame-box");
x.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.classList.add("index-navi-expended");
  this.classList.remove("index-navi-frame-box");
})
```

```css
.index-navi-expended{
width: 100%;
height: 30%;
background-color: #757575;
}
```

```html
<div class="index-navi-frame-box">
   <p>
      ABCD
      <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      1234
   </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toggleClass` to alternate between the two classes.

**HTML**

```
<div id="index-navi" class="index-navi-frame-box">
   <p id="toggleNav"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></p>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('#toggleNav').click(function() {
    $('#index-navi').toggleClass('index-navi-frame-box');
    $('#index-navi').toggleClass('index-navi-expended');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

consider follwing code,

```
<div class="index-navi-frame-box"><p onclick="customfunction()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></p></div>

<div class="index-navi-expended" id="index-expandable"></div>

<script>

function customfunction(){
  var index_expandable = document.getElementById('index-expandable');
  index_expandable.style.display = "block";
}


</script>
```